# Build of installer image failed using meta-intel

Tags: yocto

I want to use the meta-intel layer to generate an installer image of core-image-base [Guide](https://github.com/YoeDistro/meta-intel). During the compilation process, an error occurred with the error message stating that `core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.ext4` does not exist in the specified directory. However, I found that there is `core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs.ext4` in this directory. Did I overlook something?

Error message:

```
| DEBUG: Python function set_image_size finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_image_wic
| INFO: Creating image(s)...
|
| ERROR: _exec_cmd: install -m 0644 -D /home/remote/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0/deploy-core-image-base-image-complete/core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.ext4 /home/remote/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0/tmp-wic/boot.2/rootfs.img returned '1' instead of 0
| output: install: cannot stat '/home/remote/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0/deploy-core-image-base-image-complete/core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.ext4': No such file or directory
|
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/remote/workspace/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb:do_image_wic) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 6943 tasks of which 6942 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed. 
Summary: 1 task failed: /home/remote/workspace/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb:do_image_wic
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.
remote@epiroc: ~/workspace/poky/build$
```

Directory list:

```
remote@epiroc:~$ cd  workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0/deploy-core-image-base-image-complete/
remote@epiroc:~/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0/deploy-core-image-base-image-complete$ ls
core-image-base.env
core-image-base-image-installer.wks
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs-20231207012556.ext4
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs-20231207012556.manifest
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs-20231207012556.qemuboot.conf
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs-20231207012556.spdx.tar.zst
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs-20231207012556.testdata.json
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs.ext4
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs.manifest
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs.qemuboot.conf
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs.spdx.tar.zst
core-image-base-intel-corei7-64.rootfs.testdata.json
remote@epiroc:~/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0/deploy-core-image-base-image-complete$
```

The following is my configuration file
[local.conf]

```
MACHINE ??= "qemux86-64"
MACHINE ?= "intel-corei7-64"

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= "linux-intel-rt"

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " \
    vim \
    "

WKS_FILE = "image-installer.wks.in"
IMAGE_FSTYPES:append = " ext4"
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_wic = "ext4"
INITRD_IMAGE_LIVE="core-image-minimal-initramfs"
do_image_wic[depends] += "${INITRD_IMAGE_LIVE}:do_image_complete"
do_rootfs[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_deploy"
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES:append = "\
    ${KERNEL_IMAGETYPE} \
    microcode.cpio \
    ${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_BASENAME}-${MACHINE}.ext4;rootfs.img \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'grub-efi', 'grub-efi-bootx64.efi;EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'grub-efi', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg;EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', 'systemd-bootx64.efi;EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/loader/loader.conf;loader/loader.conf ', '', d)} \
    ${@bb.utils.contains('EFI_PROVIDER', 'systemd-boot', '${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot/loader/entries/boot.conf;loader/entries/boot.conf', '', d)} "
```

[bblayers.conf]

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/remote/workspace/poky/meta \
  /home/remote/workspace/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/remote/workspace/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/remote/workspace/poky/meta-intel \
  "
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the text of the errors and of the directory list instead of using screenshots.

Comment: Screenshots are not text-searchable and can't be copy-pasted easily.

Comment: @Étienne Thanks my friend!